# Specifying Ansible role dependencies at playbook level

Tags: dependencies, ansible, roles, git-submodules

I'm using [ansistrano-deploy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/detail#/role/1387) and [rvm1-ruby](https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-ansible) to deploy a Rails application, and I want to make sure `rvm1-ruby` runs before `ansistrano-deploy` *without* forking `ansistrano-deploy` to add `rvm1-ruby` as a dependency.

These roles are shared between several projects, and live in Git submodules in my `roles` directory (I'm not interested in using `ansible-galaxy`, but I don't think it does anything to help this problem):

```
.
|--roles
|  |-- rvm1-ruby                  [submodule]
|  |-- ansistrano-deploy          [submodule]
`--main.yml
```

In my `main.yml` I've included these roles:

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
  - role: rvm1-ruby
  - role: ansistrano-deploy
  tasks:
  - # ...
```

If we're deploying a Rails application, then obviously `ansistrano-deploy` can depend upon `rvm1-ruby`. I could fork `ansistrano-deploy` and add the following to `ansistrano-deploy/meta/main.yml`:

```
---
dependencies:
- { role: 'rvm1-ruby' }
```

But in my case, I'm sharing the `ansistrano-deploy` role across multiple Ansible playbooks, not all of which are used to deploy Rails applications.

Is there a way for me to specify, at the playbook-level, that `rvm1-ruby` should run before `ansistrano-deploy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really getting the problem. In your example playbook you show you add both roles to your playbook. But then your question is how you add the role as a dependency for the play... Did you mean to remove `rvm1-ruby` from the playbook and have it run solely as a magic dependency of `ansistrano-deploy`?

That would not be possible unless you modify the `meta/main.yml` of `ansistrano-deploy`, which you of course can't since it is a submodule.

You could create a 3rd role, which only contains a `meta/main.yml` adding both roles as a dependency.

```
---
dependencies:
- rvm1-ruby
- ansistrano-deploy
```

Then all you need to add to your playbooks is that new role. I use this technique in some projects where lots of dependencies are shared across playbooks. So I have a common role `dependencies` which only has a huge dependency definitions in its `meta/main.yml`.

To explicitly answer this question:

> Is there a way for me to specify, at the playbook-level, that `rvm1-ruby` should run before `ansistrano-deploy`?

Only the way you already did it, by having both roles in correct order referenced in the playbooks `roles` section.

Comment: Indeed. Turns out I had a mistake in my repository setup that meant rvm_io.rvm1-ruby didn't run. I failed to properly clone the rvm1 submodule, and rather than detecting that I was trying to run an empty role, Ansible just continued like nothing was wrong. I'll flag this question to be closed.